# javascript <span> is not working in replac() method

Tags: reactjs, sass, inline-styles

Using React with SCSS, I am trying to get span style in replace() method. but can not get it by className nor inline style.

**SCSS** :

```
.b {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

**React** :

```
<Transition in={show} timeout={100}>
    { show => (
      <div
        style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[show],
        }}
      >
        { 
          !suggestions || suggestions.length === 0 ?  errorMessage :
          suggestions.map((place, index) => {
            const regex = new RegExp(inputValue, 'gi');

            const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span style={{color: red}}>${inputValue}</span>`);
            const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span className="b">${inputValue}</span>`);
            const airportCode = place.airport.replace(regex, `<span className="b">${inputValue}</span>`);

            const resultInput = `${airportCode}, ${cityName}, ${stateName}`;
            return (
              <button 
                key={index} 
                className="black bg-darkwhite flex flex-column-m" 
                onClick={ev => {
                  handleResortInputValue(inputId, inputName, resultInput, airportCode, ev);
                }}
                >
                { resultInput }
              </button>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>`
```

** when i type 'mon' in the search input **

```
inputValue = 'mon'
suggestions = [
   {city: "montreal", state: "quebec", airport: "YMX"},
   {city: "montreal", state: "quebec", airport: "YUL"}
]
```

** It displays .. **

```
YMX, <span style={{color: red}}>mon</span>treal, quebec
YUL, <span style={{color: red}}>mon</span>treal, quebec
```

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: place.city.replace(RegExp, `<span style={{color: red}}>${inputValue}</span>`) What is the value of RegExp ? RegExp should be valid regex

Comment: The value is `event.target.value` from input.